# How does LQG solve the problem of the quantization of gravity?

Tags: quantum-gravity, topological-field-theory, loop-quantum-gravity

How does LQG solve the problem of the quantization of gravity? Not only is it a discretization of space with groups of holonomy and diffemorphisms as curved backgrounds?,is that I see that they use many difemorphisms to represent spin networks from wilson loops together with holonomy groups but I do not understand much the general idea of why difhermophisms and wilson loops, I am totally new to this, I already studied QFT but it is complicated for me a lot this area.

What does the jones polynomial do in spin networks?, Is it a discretized field topological theory? Sorry if this is very general but I have been reading and I am getting more and more confused

Comment: You should explain the abbreviation.

Comment: @my2cts It is straightforward that LQG means loop quantum gravity and QFT is quantum field theory.

Comment: @my2cts all the physist know that

Comment: Please check the spelling as well

Comment: I am not a physist.

Comment: What are "diffemorphisms"? "difemorphisms"?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.